# Difference between "have" and "make"

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> I had the essay published in the school paper.
>   I made the essay published in the school paper.

Why I can't use "make" in the sentence ?

Comment: This question looks simple, but it's quite complex and very interesting!!! Nice first question :-) Welcome to ELL.

Answer (score 1):

When you say **I [make](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make)**, you are saying that you were directly involved in what happened:

> I made some cakes - ***I personally*** spent an hour in the kitchen
>   I made his life difficult - ***I personally*** was giving him a hard time

The only exception is if you compel somebody to do something, but note that the direct object **him** or **the door** is the person or thing that you compel to do something:

> I made **him** stay at work for an extra hour. *he had to stay*
>   I made **the door** fit properly - *the door fitted*

When you say  **I [have](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/have)** with a thing as the direct object, it's either about something you experienced, or about causing something to happen (though not directly being involved). In both of these cases, the direct object is the thing that something happens to- **her bag** and **the TV**:

2.3 (with past participle) Experience or suffer the specified action happening or being done to (something)

> she **had her** bag stolen

2.4 (with object and complement) Cause to be in a particular state or condition

> I had **the TV** on with the sound turned down

When the direct object is the person or thing doing something, the meanings are the same with **make** or **have**

> I had **him** bake a cake - *he made it*
>   I made **him** bake a cake - *he made it*

When the direct object is the thing that has something done to it, the meanings are different.

> I had **a cake** baked by him - *he made it*
>   I made **a cake** - *I made it*

You may have written the essay, but you personally did not publish it: you **caused it to be published**, so you can "have it published" but you cannot "make it published".

Comment: *I had him bake a cake* and *I made him bake a cake*. Doesn't seem to fit with your explanation ...

Comment: @Araucaria, as I said, "**I made him**..." is an exception. I have updated my answer to include the two example sentences you provided.

Answer (score 1):

The two verbs take different kinds of object complements.

**have** something {clause headed by participle}

**make** something | someone {clause headed by bare infinitive}

> He had the picture **framed**.
>
> He has the rice **cooking**.

versus

> The pollen made her eyes **water**.
>
> The sad news made her **cry**.
>
> The good news made her **shout** for joy.

P.S.

or

> He made the spoon bend using telekinesis.

With respect to **have** someone {participle or bare infinitive}

> He had him debriefed.
>
> He had him laughing.
>
> He had him count to ten backwards.

Comment: This is only a quarter of the answer. The sentence *I made the essay be published in the school paper* won't work either. The object must be sentient in the *make* construction. Second thing is that *have* can take a DO + passive participle, or it can take a DO + infinitival clause, just like *make*. For example: *I had him bake the cake* and *I made him bake the cake*. This question is not at all simple!

Comment: @Araucaria: The object of "make" doesn't have to be "sentient".  *I made it break by shaking it too hard.*  or *He made the spoon bend merely by thinking it into that shape.*

Comment: OK, so in that construction  if the verb isn't ergative the object must be sentient, no? (It gets yet more complicated still!). But as  guide for usage, the distinction needs to be made ... :)

Answer (score -2):

You can **use** make in the sentence if you wish but it would serve only to indicate that you are not a native English speaker.

In short, it's not idiomatic. People don't speak like that. It's not the way English speakers talk.

There are various verb options when it comes to essays. You can read them, mark them, write them, improve them, inspire them, suggest them, consider them and a great many more.

But you can't **make them** unless you wish to display your ignorance of idiomatic English.